# Javascript dispalying day of sub values in objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display the sub values using console.log but cannot reach to it.
It's returning:

sub is not defined

Here is the data and relevant code:

```
  obj = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cat": "1",
            "sub": {
                "123": "sub1",
                "654": "sub2"
            }
        }
    ];



for (var key in obj) {

    console.log(obj[sub]); 

}
```

How can I do this? I want to display sub1 and sub2 in this case.

Comment: what does console.log(obj); give you?

Comment: It says:  sub is not defined

Comment: what does logging just the (obj) give you?

Comment: Don't you see the `[` at the beginning? That means it's an array. You have to index it to get to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nenad answer is more clean and correct. But I think this will clarify you the structure of the object you are using:

```
obj = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cat": "1",
            "sub": {
                "123": "sub1",
                "654": "sub2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "cat": "2",
            "sub": {
                "abc": "sub3",
                "def": "sub4"
            }
        }
    ];


for (var index in obj) {
    for (var indexSub in obj[index].sub) {
      console.log(indexSub + ': ' + obj[index].sub[indexSub]); 
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
123: sub1
654: sub2
abc: sub3
def: sub4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `map()`.

```js
var obj = [{
  "id": "1",
  "cat": "1",
  "sub": {
    "123": "sub1",
    "654": "sub2"
  }
}];

var s = Object.keys(obj[0].sub).map(e => obj[0].sub[e]);
console.log(s)
```